# No data is available for the requested resource

Tags: javascript, xml, domdocument, msxml

I am using below js code to load the xml in ms:

```
var dsoToolBar;
dsoToolBar = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0");
dsoToolBar.async = false;
dsoToolBar.load('Toolbar.xml');
```

The above code is working fine for OS Windows 7 and before with some specialized IE settings.
Now I'm testing the same code in Windows 8 machine with same IE settings.
But the load function in above code fails with the error

No data is available for the requested resource.

And the xml is not loaded in dom object.

I found the solution for this on below link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/281142

My modified code is:

```
dsoToolBar.load('Toolbar.xml');
if (dsoToolBar.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
  var myErr = dsoToolBar.parseError;
  dsoToolBar.setProperty("ServerHTTPRequest",true);
  dsoToolBar.load('Toolbar.xml');
}
```

This works in both Windows 8 and previous versions of windows.

But since the code is working fine for previous versions of windows, I suppose there is some IE or xml parser related issue in my Windows 8 machine.

What extra IE or xml parser settings can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The article is from 2011, I recommend using AJAX (xhr) to fetch the xml file.

Comment: Does using `new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")` instead of `new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0")` fix the problem?

Comment: The same code is working for windows 7 and lower versions of windows. Problem is for windows 8 machine only. So looking for a fix related to xml parser or ie settings than the code change.

Comment: Martin Honnen: No, the problem still persists.